# How to Download Directory from Github

Tags: c#, github, octokit

hi i want to download a directory from github account how can i do this? for example i want to download manifest folder from test acount:

```
github.com/test/projectx/manifest
```

I don't want to use github API as much as possible but I tested Octokit It's like taking the folder as a byte, but I couldn't turn it into a folder on my system

```
 var archiveBytes = await client.Repository.Content.GetArchive("octokit", "octokit.net", ArchiveFormat.Zipball);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to `clone` repository to your local machine you can do as follow.

You will want to use `LibGit2Sharp` library, You can install it using:

**NuGet Package Manager (Visual Studio)** [NuGet link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp)

```
Install-Package LibGit2Sharp
```

-or-

**.NET Core CLI**

```
dotnet add package LibGit2Sharp
```

Then simply use:

```
Repository.Clone("https://github.com/EdiWang/EnvSetup.git", @"D:\EnvSetup");
```

For more details see: [Operate git with net core](https://edi.wang/post/2019/3/26/operate-git-with-net-core)

Answer (score -3):

Do you need to download it on an application or juste in another folder ? In this case you can click the "download or clone" button on the github respository, download the zip and extract the file you want then open them in your IDE. Otherwise you can use the git command

```
cd /yourWorkingDirectory
git init
git clone
git status
```

then you'll be able to acess all the files of the github's directory in your WorkingDirectory.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I think OP ask for `c#` programmatic solution

Comment: var isn't use in ```c#```because the var dont have a type

Comment: From Microsoft docs: [var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)

Comment: They keyword `var` is in use in `c#` it is strongly type, but is syntactic sugar. Personally I dislike it, but it is fairly common